# Android JSON post to WCF Service

Tags: android, json, wcf, post

I having a problem with my android client trying to post a JSON class to my wcf service.
Here is the code for android client :

```
    public HttpResponse TestPost() throws Exception 
{

    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url+"/TestPost");

    JSONStringer img = new JSONStringer()
        .object()
        .key("TestModel")
            .object()
                .key("p1").value("test")
                .key("p2").value("test")
                .key("p3").value(1)
                .key("p4").value("test")
                .key("p5").value(2)
                .key("p6").value("test;test")
            .endObject()
        .endObject();
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(img.toString());

    httpost.setEntity(se);

    httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    return httpclient.execute(httpost);
}
```

Here is code for Wcf

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "TestPost")]
    void TestPost(TestModel tm);





[DataContract]
public class TestModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "p1")]
    public string p1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "p2")]
    public string p2{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "p3")]
    public int p3 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "p4")]
    public string p4 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "p5")]
    public int p5 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "p6")]
    public string p6 { get; set; }
```

}

In my wcf method the parameter TestModel tm is always null. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: have you checked the json that is getting generated?

Comment: Yepp, it's getting generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrapping of the object (since you specified `WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`) is done based on the parameter **name**, not the parameter type. The name of the outermost JSON member should be "tm", not "TestModel":

```
public HttpResponse TestPost() throws Exception  
{ 
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url+"/TestPost"); 

    JSONStringer img = new JSONStringer() 
        .object() 
        .key("tm") 
            .object() 
                .key("p1").value("test") 
                .key("p2").value("test") 
                .key("p3").value(1) 
                .key("p4").value("test") 
                .key("p5").value(2) 
                .key("p6").value("test;test") 
            .endObject() 
        .endObject(); 
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(img.toString()); 

    httpost.setEntity(se); 

    httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
    httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); 

    return httpclient.execute(httpost); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks , missed that :) . I also needed to set content type and content encoding to UTF-8 in order to get i to work.



StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString());                         entity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
httpost.setEntity(entity);