# Consume wcf service in android

Tags: android, wcf

I have a method upload in WCF service

```
    [OperationContract]
    public bool Upload(ImageFile image)

    { ............
      //some Insert statement
      ............
    }
```

Here's the gist of what I wrote in my ImageFile class:

```
public class ImageFile
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string LoginTime { get; set; }

    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    public byte[] Imagestream { get; set; }
}
```

How do I consume this service from android?

Comment: What did [Google](https://www.google.com/search?source=ig&rlz=1G1ACGW_ENUS358&q=MySqlDataReader+HasRows+property&oq=MySqlDataReader+HasRows+property&gs_l=igoogle.3..0i22i30.198817.207242.0.207954.44.28.3.13.6.0.212.3109.12j15j1.28.0...0.0...1ac.1.vhTnaC2M-EQ#rlz=1G1ACGW_ENUS358&sclient=psy-ab&q=Consume+WCF+service+in+Android&oq=Consume+WCF+service+in+Android&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i22i30l2.48892.52908.0.53061.30.21.0.8.8.0.188.2662.3j18.21.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.WGt5HsTP6tg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.cGE&fp=6c8e275c38a73745&biw=1366&bih=703) tell you?

Comment: Could you Please google this.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361107/WCF-and-Android-Part-II

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android JSON post to WCF Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922570/android-json-post-to-wcf-service)